# PHP вызывать функцию до тех пор пока не вернет true

Tags: php, функции, рекурсия, return

У меня есть функция, которая проверят на наличие в бд такого же имени пользователя.

```
function check_username ($name) {
    global $db;
    $status = null;
    $check = $db->m_query("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
    if  ($check->num_rows > 0) {
        $status = false;
    } else {
        $status = true;
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Данная функция отрабатывает при нажатий на кнопку. В результате выполняется код, если я получил false, то к текущему имени я добавлю слово "TWO", но как мне вызвать повторно функцию и в параметр передать новую переменную содержащая новое имя `$new_username` и вызывать до тех пор пока функция не вернет true?

```
$check_name = check_username($username);
if (!$check_name) {
  $new_username = $username."TWO";
}
```

Comment: `while` вам нужен, а не рекурсия

Comment: Может просто сказать пользователю что это имя занято, а не городить суффиксы?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так получается:

```
$check_name = check_username($username);
$new_username = $username;
while (!$check_name) {
  $new_username .= "TWO";
  $check_name = check_username($new_username);
}
```

---

Смотрите, чтоб если зарегистрируется 100 людей с ником `userTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWOTWO` чтоб не были проблемы с базой. Если у вас поле `VARCHAR(100)` к примеру, база будет обрезать добавленное имя пользователя и может получится так что при проверке будут разные логины, а после добавления в базу - одинаковые.

Потому лучше добавлять рандом - так больше шансов получить короткий логин:

```
$check_name = check_username($username);
$new_username = $username;
while (!$check_name) {
  $new_username .= rand(0, 9);
  $check_name = check_username($new_username);
}
```